# How to start application to show books and prices, and lets you purchase through checkout?

Tags: android, google-checkout

How would i go about building a application that lets users see books that i write, and the prices and the ability to purchase the books through google checkout??

How would i go about doing this or start? If i already have a website with my content on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be a good learning resource.

[Link](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/)

**EDIT:**
you can browse the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/).

this is the video the that project. [Link](http://progx.org/users/Gfx/shelves/shelves.mov).

you can install the app from here. [Link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.miadzin.shelves)

i guess its under Apache 2.0 license. check the author's comment. [Link](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/01/19/shelves-an-open-source-android-application/).

Comment: Looks like something im looking for! How do i see the tutorial? Or how they implemented it?

Comment: Where do i see the tutorial on the link your provided?

Comment: there is a source tab, you can download the source using SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do this as a web application, have a look at the Google Books API:

http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/getting-started.html